# Wanting to send information to a different html than the one the onclick event was on

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently trying to make my shopping cart work(at least minimally). For that to happen I need to update a label or somehow get access to an HTML file that has the shopping cart information. The main page which has the button to add an item to the shopping cart is not the page I want to access.

Here's the HTML with the buttons(onclick):
This file is called "AllItems.html"

```
<div class = "island-item"> 
  <img  class = "itemImg" src="assestsForProductsPage/IslandTimeHolderShirt.png" alt="Hawaiian Shirt 1">
  <center>Hawaiian Shirt 1</center>
  <div class="priceAmount">
    $60
    <img id = "Hawaiian Shirt 1" onclick = "addToCart('Hawaiian Shirt 1')" class = "addCartImg" src="assestsForProductsPage/plusSignForCart.jpeg" alt="addCart">
   </div>
</div>
```

Here's the javaScript code:

```
function addToCart(item)
{
 document.getElementById('islandTimeCartLabel') = item;
}
```

Here's the HTML code for the file I want the javaScript function to update:
The file is called "islandTimeCart"

```
<body>
 Island Time Cart
 <label id = "islandTimeCartLabel">
        
 </label>
</body>
```

As you can see I try and get the labels id inside the function addToCart but don't think this is legal.

Can someone show me how to 1)Access a different HTML file than the one the onclick event is on and 2)How to print text to that file

All help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Research how to use `.getElementById`. This is not a valid usage: `document.getElementById('islandTimeCartLabel') = item;`. You should use `.innerHTML` or `.textContent` in order to change its text.

Comment: `the HTML code for the file I want the javaScript function to update` that file is not in the browser, so it can't access it - imagine the havoc one could wreak!!!

Comment: @ErhanÇapar I tried using .innerHTML but had no luck

Comment: @JaromandaX The file could be accessed by a hyperlinked image of a shopping cart. Not sure if this helps but still not sure how I would access that file. How does a shopping cart get updated on clothing websites? How do they access that file?

Comment: I am sorry I did not read the first paragraph of the question properly. What you are describing can be done through a backend server, where you save the information about the items on a server. `Node.js` is one of the most popular ways you can do it. You can also use `localStorage`, which would be simpler.